# How get android cpu model name?

Tags: java, android, linux

I want to learn my phone cpu model name and I tryed to use /proc/cpuinfo and a lot of code but I failed. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do not put irrelevant tags on your question - this has nothing to do with activities or intents.  It's unclear why you removed "java" as that presumably is relevant to how you want to parse this.  "Linux" could also be relevant as the information originates at that level.

Answer (score 7):

Run

```
$ adb shell cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code

```
public static String getCpuName() {
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("/proc/cpuinfo");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String text = br.readLine();
        br.close();
        String[] array = text.split(":\\s+", 2);
        if (array.length >= 2) {
            return array[1];
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

What about your code?

Comment: There are two screenshot.First one is myapp ( using /proc/cpuinfo like ur function) second one is Antutu Tester.  [MyApp](http://i.imgur.com/pOXHWTr.png)  [Antutu Tester](http://i.imgur.com/FkpRC1t.png)